# How to deal with extra "/" in phpleague route?

Tags: php, web-services, routes

I am setting endpoints for my web application like this:

```
$router = new League\Route\RouteCollection;

function user_action (Request $request, Response $response) {
    // some logic
    .
    .
    .
    return $response;
}

$router->addRoute('GET', '/user', 'user_action');
```

**/user** endpoint works well.

However when I use **/user/** (extra slash in the end) I get a

**League\Route\Http\Exception\NotFoundException**

I want both endpoints to point to same function.
I can achieve the desired behavior by adding routes for both endpoints separately:

```
$router->addRoute('GET', '/user', 'user_action');
$router->addRoute('GET', '/user/', 'user_action');
```

What is the recommended way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options

1. You can use htaccess to strip the trailing slash from the url.
2. Send the dispatcher the url without the trailing slash.

## Solution 1: htaccess

Add the following rewrite rule to your .htacces:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

## Solution 2: dispatcher

After you've created the router from a RouteCollection, you get the dispatcher and dispatch the routes:

```
$router = new RouteCollection();
$dispatcher = $router->getDispatcher();
$response = $dispatcher->dispatch($request->getMethod(), $request->getPathInfo());
```

The url which is send to the dispatcher can easily be adjusted:

```
$url = $request->getPathInfo();

// if url ends with a slash, remove it
$url = rtrim($url, '/');

$response = $dispatcher->dispatch($request->getMethod(), $url);
```

Two easy solutions, which one you use depends on you.

Comment: Second solution can be made easier by `rtrim($url, '/')`